# How to make MS Access 2007 form code work in module

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I don't know if this is possible, but...

I have several forms containing the same code but they all have different data based on different query's.

When I update the code in one form, I have to make the same changes on all other forms.

To make the update process simple, I moved the forms code to a module but the forms stopped working.

How can I call the events from a module?

This is an example of a code in a form, that I would to use on all my forms:

```
Public Sub CallSkype_Click()
Dim strProgramName As String
Dim strArgument As String
strProgramName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe"
strArgument = "/callto:+01" & Me.Phone & ""
Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", 
vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Comintern Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

Pass an instance of the form as a parameter and use it to replace `Me`:

```
Public Sub CallSkypeHandler(instance As Object)
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String
    strProgramName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe"
    strArgument = "/callto:+01" & instance.Phone & ""
    Shell """" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

From the calling form:

```
Public Sub CallSkype_Click()
    CallSkypeHandler Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another option is to pass the phone number as a variable to the function:

```
' sub in module
Public Sub MakeSkypeCall(PhoneNumber As String)
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String

    strProgramName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe"
    strArgument = "/callto:+01" & PhoneNumber
    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", _
            vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Then, your forms would just call that sub, passing the phone number to call:

```
' calling sub from form
Public Sub CallSkype_Click()
    MakeSkypeCall Me.Phone
End Sub
```

With this approach, you can easily test the code without even using a form.

You may also want to consider not hard-coding the program path for Skype in your code: If other users are using the database, there's no guarantee that Skype will be installed in this location.

Answer (score 1):

ComIntern's answer is certainly valid. But you can also adjust the code to make use of the currently active form:

```
Public Sub CallSkype()
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String
    strProgramName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe"
    strArgument = "/callto:+01" & Screen.ActiveForm!Phone.Value & ""
    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", 
    vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

An advantage is that then you can set events to `=CallSkype()` instead of writing a separate event handler. A disadvantage is that it won't support reports, and might act strange with subforms.